# If $ f $ is a scalar field and $ f(a) \neq 0 $, then there is an $ n $-ball in which $ f $ has the same sign as $ f(a) $.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, scalar-fields

I’ve tried to prove the following theorem:

> Let $ f $ be a scalar field that is continuous at an interior point $ a $ of
>     $ S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n} $. If $ f(a) \neq 0 $, then there is an
>     $ n $-ball $ \mathbb{B}(a) $ in which $ f $ has the same sign as $ f(a) $.

However, I’m not sure if my proof is correct, and honestly, I didn’t like the way that I proceeded, so I’m look for alternative proofs/proof methods for such theorems. Moreover, I’m looking for advice on the way that I wrote my proof.

*Proof*.

We will prove that 
$$
(\exists \delta > 0)[(0 < |x - a| < \delta) \to (|f(a) - f(x)| < |f(a)|)].
$$
As
$$
(\forall \epsilon > 0)(\exists \delta_{1} > 0)
[(0 < |x - a|< \delta_{1}) \to (|f(a) - f(x)| < \epsilon)],
$$
if we pick $ \epsilon $ so that $ 0 < \epsilon < |f(a)| $, and $ 0 < \delta \leq \delta_{1} $, then the inequality becomes
$$
(\exists \delta > 0)[(0 < |x - a| < \delta) \to (|f(a) - f(x)| < \epsilon)].
$$
The theorem is therefore proved.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f(a)>0$ Then choose $\epsilon=\frac{f(a)}{2}$

Then $\frac{f(a)}{2}<f(x)<\frac{3f(a)}{2}$ for all $x\in B(a,\delta)$