# $2^{-n}\varphi(x/n) $ does not converge in $\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, uniform-convergence, distribution-theory

Let $\varphi \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n)= \mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^n) $ be a test function. Prove that

1. $2^{-n}\varphi \to 0 $ in $\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$
2. $2^{-n}\varphi(x/n)  $ does not converge in $\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$

**Definition**

My definition of converge in $\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is that:

Given sequence $\varphi_n \in \mathscr{D}(\Omega)$, $\varphi \in \mathscr{D}(\Omega)$. We say that $\varphi_n \to \varphi  $ in $\mathscr{D}(\Omega)$ if

a)  $\operatorname{supp}(\varphi_n) \subseteq K$,  $K$ compact

b)$D^\alpha\varphi_n \to D^\alpha\varphi  $ uniformly over $K$, $ \forall 
 $ multi-index $ \alpha \in \mathbb{N}^n$

**My try**

1)

a) $\operatorname{supp}(\varphi_n)=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n:\varphi_n(x) \neq 0 \} =\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n:2^{-n}\varphi(x) \neq 0 \}=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n:\varphi(x) \neq 0 \}=\operatorname{supp}(\varphi)\subseteq K$

b) $D^\alpha\varphi_n(x) = 2^{-n}D^\alpha\varphi(x) \to 0D^\alpha\varphi =0  $ uniformly over $K$, $ \forall 
 $ multi-index $ \alpha \in \mathbb{N}^n$

2. I don't know what to do

Comment: For (b), suppose $\phi$ is non-zero on the ball $B_1$ of radius $1$. In other words, $B_1\subset \text{supp}(\phi)$. WHat can you say about the supports of the functions $f_n(x)=2^{-n}\phi(x/n)$? Are the supports getting bigger or smaller? Therefore...

Comment: @peek-a-boo They seem to be getting smaller, $2^{-n}$ is tending to $0$, and $\phi(x/n)$ seems to be shrinking to $\phi(0) $. So I would say $f_n(x) $converges to $0$. But that is the opposite of what I must prove. What am I missing?

Comment: The support of $\phi (x/n)$ becomes bigger and bigger, hence it goes outside any compact set as $n \to \infty$

Comment: @Crostul for each fixed n, can't K  change to get big enough to hold the support of $\phi(x/n)$?. And how would you write it down more explicitly?

Comment: As you wrote in your question, you say that convergence requires the condition $$\mathrm{supp} ( \phi_n ) \subseteq K$$ where $K$ is compact. This means that $K$ does not depend on $n$, otherwise it would be $$\mathrm{supp} ( \phi_n ) \subseteq K_n$$ However this latter condition is superfluous since by definition every $\phi_n$ already has compact support.

Answer (score 1):

1. For b) maybe you should write: "since $\varphi \in \mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$", given $\alpha$ there exists $c$ such that $\| D^{\alpha}\varphi \|_{\infty}<c$. Then
   $$  \|2^{-n}D^{\alpha} \varphi\|_{\infty} \leq 2^{n}c \to 0. $$
2. Assume that there exists $\psi \in \mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ such that $2^{n}\varphi(x/n) \to \psi(x)$. Since $\psi \in \mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, its support is contained in some ball $B(0,R)$. Now notice that $\mathrm{supp}(2^{n}\varphi(x/n))=\mathrm{supp}(\varphi(x/n))=n\mathrm{supp}(\varphi)$. By continuity (and that $\varphi$ is not the zero function), there exists a ball $B(x_{0},\varepsilon) \subset \mathrm{supp}(\varphi)$. Then $nB(x_{0},\varepsilon) \subset n\mathrm{supp}(\varphi)$. Now take $n$ big enough such that $nB(x,\varepsilon) \supset B(0,R)$. This contradicts condition b) in your definition of convergence beacuse $\mathrm{supp}(2^{n}\varphi(x/n))=n \mathrm{supp}(\varphi) \supset B(0,R)$.

**EDIT:** Proving that $n\mathrm{supp}(\varphi)=\mathrm{supp}(\varphi/n)$

Let $x \in \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}; \varphi(x)=0\}$. Then $nx$ satisfies $\varphi(nx/n)=\varphi(x)=0$. Thus $nx \in \{y \in \mathbb{R}^{n};\varphi(y/n)\}$, that is, $n\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}; \varphi(x)=0\} \subset  \{y \in \mathbb{R}^{n};\varphi(y/n)\}$.

Now take $y \in \{y \in \mathbb{R}^{n};\varphi(y/n)\}$. Then $y/n$ satisfies $\varphi(y/n)=0$, that is, $y/n \in \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}; \varphi(x)=0\}$, which is equivalent to say that $y \in n\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}; \varphi(x)=0\}$. Then $\{y \in \mathbb{R}^{n};\varphi(y/n)\} \subset n\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}; \varphi(x)=0\}$.

So far
$$\{y \in \mathbb{R}^{n};\varphi(y/n)\} = n\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}; \varphi(x)=0\}.$$
Now look at the complements and take closure to obtain $\mathrm{supp}(\varphi(x/n))=n\mathrm{supp}(\varphi)$.

Comment: why are you using the infinity norm? And in 2, why should the first ball be centered at 0? This is something I've been seeing around but I can't get my head around it. I think that in principle the ball could be anywhere, couldn't it?

Comment: Yes, the ball could be anywhere, but only for simplicity I choosed a ball centered at zero. Since $K$ is compact, in particular is bounded and therefore there is contained in some ball $B=B(y,r)$. This ball is contained in some other ball centered at zero (take a ball with radious $=d(0,B)+r+2021$).

Comment: The infinity norm is the same as say uniform. Indeed, recall that for $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$
$$ \|f\|_{\infty}=\sup _{x \in X} |f(x)|.$$
Thus $f \to 0$ uniformly iff $\|f\|_{\infty} \to 0$.

Comment: is f a sequence of functions in your last example? And does this property hold for converge to a non zero function?

Comment: Could you proof this part: $\mathrm{supp}(\varphi(x/n))=n\mathrm{supp}(\varphi)$ ? I was mistakingly taking the limit inside the argument and getting $ \varphi(x/n) \to\varphi(0)$

Comment: @J.C.VegaO I added it to my answers

Comment: "By continuity (and that $\varphi$ is not the zero function), there exists a ball $B(x_{0},\varepsilon) \subset \mathrm{supp}(\varphi)$", what definition of continuity is this? It looks more to me like the definition of open set

Comment: No, it is continuity of $\varphi$. Since $\varphi$ is not zero, there exists $x_{0} \in \mathrm{supp}(\varphi)$. By continuity of $\varphi$, there exists a $\varepsilon>0$ such that $\varphi(x) \neq 0$ in $B(x_{0},\varepsilon)$. Thus $B(x_{0},\varepsilon) \subset \mathrm{supp}(\varphi)$. I really do not understand why you said that this is by "openess", since $\mathrm{supp}(\varphi)$ is not necessarily an open set.

Comment: Yes, of course  it is no an open set, my point was that the existence of an open ball inside something is the definition of openess of that something, of course it doesn't hold here. I just having trouble recognizing this as a definition of continuity. Still don't see it. One is supposed to take the epsilon-open ball in the codomain of the function centered at $\varphi(x_0)$ and then  a delta-open ball centered at $x_0$should exist in the domain such that $\varphi (x)$is less than delta of $\varphi(x_0)$. But I don't see where all these missing elements are

Comment: Instead you are saying that the epsilon exists, instead of just taking it and stating the existence of the delta

Comment: $\varepsilon$ is just a dummy variable. This a well-known application of continuity and you can find a proof in several post, e.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1998829/if-f-is-a-scalar-field-and-fa-neq-0-then-there-is-an-n-ball-in-w?rq=1